# How can I determine the form of a geometric series in a recurrence relation by using iterative substitution?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science, substitution, geometric-series

This question is based more in computer science however I think a mathematics approach is probably better. When solving a recurrence relation using iterative substitution you generally need to find the pattern of the constant function to the right of $T(\frac{n}{2})$. The sequence usually forms a geometric series and I'm supposed to simplify it to find the solution of the recurrence equation. However, I'm not sure how to do that. Some of them are not as obvious as this for example:

$$1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Here is an example: [iterative substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsKS.png)

As you can see, the geometric series turns into $3^i - 1$, but why not $2\cdot3^i$? I'm sure my professor used some sort of formula from the geometric series like the basic one I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

He just use this:
$$1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\ \quad\forall x\ne 1\quad\forall n\ge 1$$
A simple derivation can be:
$$(x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})=x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}+x^n-1-x-...-x^{n-1}=x^n-1$$

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but like I said not all series adhere to that form. What other formulas are common in geometric series or do I use the derivation that you used as a basis for all series?

Comment: Unfortunately there are not in general formulas like this for series except for arithmetic or geometric series. The advice I give to you is to solve as much you can lots of exercises involving series. After that you will get lots of tools to tackle some series.

Comment: Alright thanks but here is another example: https://imgur.com/qtbzfID. It's essentially analogous to the previous iterative substitution but the sequence is recurring on the denominator instead.

Comment: It is always a geometric series with $x=\frac13$